# Remove substring before last occurrence of a special character in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to remove the substring before last occurrence of period`(.)`. The Query should convert `r.k.Lee Brown` to `Lee Brown`. So, basically I need the substring before last dot `.` and replace it with `''`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@str)) - 1)
```

You can slightly modify the above using:

```
REVERSE('.' + @str))
```

instead of

```
REVERSE(@str)
```

just in case there are *no* `'.'` in `@str`.

Comment: nice solution, with only one invocation of reverse.

Comment: This is working fine when my string has a '.'. But not when my string is not having a comma. So I used a CASE-WHEN block.                SELECT Case when charindex('.','fadafaddfgsdsdfdaas') >1 then RIGHT('fadafaddfgsdsdfdaas', CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('fadafaddfgsdsdfdaas')) - 1) else 'fadafaddfgsdsdfdaas' end as "processed o/p"

Comment: It's perfect after your edit. Thanks @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: In case anyone lands here looking for PostgreSQL solution: RIGHT(@str, POSITION('.' IN REVERSE(@str)) - 1)

Answer (score 0):

Like This

```
declare @a as nvarchar(100)='r.k.Lee Brown'
select reverse(substring(reverse(@a),0,charindex('.',reverse(@a))))
```

**EDIT:**

If you have no `'.'` in string

```
declare @a as nvarchar(100)='r.k.Lee Brown'
select reverse(substring(reverse(@a),0,charindex('.',reverse('.'+@a))))

set @a = 'Lee Brown'
select reverse(substring(reverse(@a),0,charindex('.',reverse('.'+@a))))
```

Comment: This works perfectly when my string has a comma. But, not when my string is not having a comma. like: fadafaddfgsdsdfdaas. I guess I will need to use CASE-WHEN for this to work with strings without comma

Answer (score 0):

Use REVERSE and Substring Function:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(50) = 'r.k.Lee Brown'

SELECT Reverse(Substring(Reverse(@var), 0, Charindex('.', Reverse(@var))))
```