# Keeping string only after last character for full table update

Tags: sql-server

I want to do an SQL update and remove any characters before and including "\".

I found SQL Reverse and looked at code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752258/remove-substring-before-last-occurrence-of-a-special-character-in-sql-server/30752314#30752314) which suggests

```
SELECT RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@str)) - 1)
```

or

```
SELECT RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('\', '\' + REVERSE(@str)) - 1)
```

Is the modification below the best way to do update on a SQL table:

```
UPDATE [DB].dbo._tbldata 
SET DOCURL =  RIGHT(DOCURL, CHARINDEX('\',  REVERSE('\' + DOCURL)) - 1)
```

and should I add

```
WHERE DOCURL LIKE '%\%'
```

Comment: How many slashes can be in your string?  Can you show sample data?

Comment: Oh I think about 10 is the record at the moment they would be URLs but they are the companies external URL and we only need a local file name. i.e http:\\www.bbc.co.uk\folder\folder2\folder3\folders4\filename.pdf would become filename.pdf

Comment: I should say this is only for the bulk uploads thankfully we normally will have XML import and can tidy on the fly.

Comment: Your current approach looks basically correct (I have not tested it), namely reversing the string to find the last slash, then using `RIGHT` after that.

Comment: Fab, that's the main thing. Wanted to ensure the right process for the job but as it was mainly an amend to someone elses code (that I linked to) I felt codereview was not quite the right place.

Comment: Thought I don't know why you _append_ a slash here: `REVERSE('\' + DOCURL)`

Comment: If I don't and there is no \ then I lose the filename so if it was just "filename.pdf" I would lose that

Comment: Yeah, but if there _is_ a slash, then I think it would break the logic.  The answer by @Ullas is probably what you want to use.  An HTTP URL will never not have at least one slash in it AFAIK.

Comment: Fair enough, I think I phrased my query slightly wrong as I would want to keep the data as well if there was no slash (because customer data...) but I take the below onboard as the answer and can use with/without depending.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHARINDEX` and `RIGHT`.

**Query**

```
select right(DOCURL, charindex('\', reverse(DOCURL), 1) - 1)
from [your_table_name]
where DOCURL like '%\%';
```

And if you want to update, then

**Query**

```
update [your_table_name]
set DOCURL = (
   case when DOCURL like '%\%' then right(DOCURL, charindex('\', reverse(DOCURL), 1) - 1)
   else DOCURL END
);
```